# ArcMap MODIS NDVI for district in India?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, modis, ndvi, hdf

I am working on 159 `HDF` files for the India subcontinent. I am trying to get min, max, standard deviation from the different districts of India using shapefiles.

How do I make all the `HDF` files to represent the min, max and stddev for each district using ArcMap 10.3.1?

Comment: It would be good if you were to provide more details about what you tried and what isn't working. I think the tools you're looking for are, "clip" and "extent"